# AsyncStorage.getItem React Native. Runs multiple time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Im fetching a value from the LocalStorage but when using the KeyFetch() function it runs multiple times aswell as the code in the same block as the function

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { useState } from "react";

function keyFetch() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
    const getKey = async () => {
      var key = "";
      try {
        key = await AsyncStorage.getItem('scheduleKey');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("The given key does not exist")
      }
      return key;
    };
    
    getKey().then(data => {
      
      setValue(data)

    })
    
    
    if (value != undefined && !fetched) {
      fetched = true
      return value
    }
    

    
  }

  export default keyFetch
```

I want to run it in a view later but rn i just run it in console.log()

```
const Hem = ({}) => {
    console.log(keyFetch())
}
```

when ever I run this function the code and the code in the same block runs multiple times. I this creates problems when trying to actually use it.

this is what it outputs, as you can see in picture it runs 3 times and outputs undefined, the actual data and then undefined again.

[console output when the code is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZoOG.png)

I've tried alot to use await and such but this is the only way that I get the value without it being stuck in pending status.

Comment: Can you show where you are using the Hem function?

Comment: @IvanAllue Its run from the app.js code
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function App() {
 
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarShowLabel: false, headerShown: false})}
            >
          <Tab.Screen name = "Hem" component = {Hem} options={{tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=><Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={25}/>}}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
  
  
}